# Elastic Beanstalk Error, Worked for several months

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My group had a web application running using Elastic Beanstalk. For several months, it worked fine, but now the website shows the error

'radiology-ai-env.eba-wgmpba4k.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com is currently unable to handle this request.'

When I try to rebuild the environment, I get two error messages:

1.) LaunchWaitCondition failed. The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized within the given time. Rebuild the environment. If this persists, contact support.

2.) Stack named 'awseb-e-pw8nbmshem-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

I am wondering what can be changed to fix this issue, and would appreciate any help. Thank you so much in advance!! I can follow up with more info if it is helpful.